# Need to create 2 arrays with random numbers and then sort both of them in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have a little problem. I need to create 2 arrays. First I have to sort each of them and then I have write them in sorted order in main function . Any way? I am hopeless..
I Have no idea how to declare array in function. So I can call the sort function from main.
Here is my program

```
int array_a()
{
int i,switchh,switching;
 int howmany = 10;
 int a[howmany];
 for (i=0;i<howmany;i++)
 {
    a[i] = rand() % 10+1;
 }
 for (i=0; i<howmany;i++)
 while(1){

    switchh=0;

  for (i=0; i<howmany-1;i++){
  if (a[i]>a[i+1]){
    int switching=a[i];
    a[i]=a[i+1];
    a[i+1]=switching;
    switchh = 1;
  } 
  }
  if(switchh==0)
  {
    break;
  }

}
}
int array_b()
{
     int i,switchh,switching;
 int howmany = 10;
 int b[howmany];
 for (i=0;i<howmany;i++)
 {
    b[i] = rand() % 10+1;
 }
 while(1){

    switchh=0;

  for (i=0; i<howmany-1;i++){
  if (b[i]>b[i+1]){
    int switching=b[i];
    b[i]=b[i+1];
    b[i+1]=switching;
    switchh = 1;
  } 
  }
  if(switchh==0)
  {
    break;
  }

}
}
main()
{
 return 0;      
}
```

Comment: "i have in main sort both of them and write them sorted together." not formated well, I ment  That i have to sort it once both of them together and then write them sorted for eg. function a has random numbers like 1,2,3 , function b has numbers 2,3,4 and in output it should write 1,2,2,3,3,4

Comment: there is as well ment to be sort besides of sorth in header :D sorry

Comment: You have some basic syntax errors, for example `int kolko = 10, ;` Why don't you fix that first. Get the program to compile without errors. Also the declaration for `a` is not shown. Please show all of your minimum program.

Comment: yeah i saw atm, i have been deleting all stuff from main function because it showed not to work and i forgot to delete "," fixed now. well basicaly there is a[kolko] and kolko = 10; isn´t that enought to declare it?

Comment: i as well saw that there is one more thing to change in for cycles and other cycles in function where i declared b.. but that doesn´t matter right now.. thing i need is that I need to sort both arrays a and b in main that i sort first in functions upside so they come sorted for another resort..

Comment: 1. Your sample code is terribly formatted and thus hard to read. 2. English identifiers (variable names, function names) would make understanding of sample code easier. (Otherwise, it's hard to read.) 3. Please, use [edit] to edit and improve your question.

Comment: You should seriously try to compile it first. I am sure that the compiler complains about some syntax errors. So first fix them, it also helps you to learn reading compiler errors. Furthermore, are you sure that you need 2 functions to do the same thing? Isn't one function with some parameters enough?

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49115947/edit) your question and show the version which compiles successfully.

Comment: Edited it into english version, also deleted main hmm yes i tryed one function but second array was randomizing stupid numbers.. First array - a[howmany] was randomizing numbers nice but b[howmany] was randomizing numbers like -1 453164 0 etc.. not numbers from 0 to 9

Comment: Any ideas on how to sort it in one function?

Comment: EDIT: It´s compiling now. No syntax errors, all clear. Last thing to do is to write main and declare array in functions that i can call into main to sort them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To write a sort function declare a function like `void sort(int *arr, int count)`, pass the array to this function. Note that you should call `srand()` at once at the beginning of the program to get a better random distribution. Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void sort(int arr[], int howmany)
{
    int i, switchh;
    while(1)
    {
        switchh = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < howmany - 1; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            {
                int switching = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = switching;
                switchh = 1;
            }
        }
        if(switchh == 0)
            break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int howmany = 10;
    int arr[howmany];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
        arr[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    for(i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
        printf("%2d, ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    sort(arr, howmany);
    for(i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
        printf("%2d, ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god man thank you very much! That was what i was asking for, now i know how to continue and how to add second one.. But still one more question. In sort function there was no declared howmany anywhere, just in main how is that possible? Thanks alot!

Comment: `howmany` is a *"parameter"* in the function `void sort(int arr[], int howmany)`. You are passing the array and the size of array to the function. You can click the check mark to accept the answer if that solves it.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Thanks alot!